# Slicing a dictionary's value isn't working properly

Tags: python, json, dictionary, slice, discord.py

So I have a json file which contains role ids (a dictionary named roles),with a key (which is the name of the role) and each key has the role's id as it's value

**Looks something like this:**

`{"Ban": ["694175790639743076"], "Muted": ["692863646543380590"]}`

I mostly just need the ids from the json

**using something like `roles['Muted']` or `roles.get('Muted')` gives me `['692863646543380590']`:**
`Muted=roles.get('Muted')`
`print(Muted)`

the functions take integers,so I have to remove `['` from the output and get this: `692863646543380590`

slicing just gives me `[]` no matter what slicing I use:
`work=boost1[2:20]` `*or any other slice*`
`print(work)`
gives out `"[]"`

**why is slicing just not working here? and how do I fix this??**

Comment: are you trying to slice the number inside the list `[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all `roles['Muted']` is a list, if you want just first element then get it with `0` index then try using `int()` for converting it to Integer:

```
Muted=int(roles.get('Muted')[0]) # or Muted=int(roles['Muted'][0])
```

Muted will be:

```
692863646543380590
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
work = int(boost1[0]) #fetching the first element of list and converting it into int
```